# how to send data from an activity back to a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am very confused on how to send data between a fragment and an activity, since I found how to send data between activities and even fragments but not from an activity that is called from a fragment (which I think is different because I tried those methods and they didn't work).

In my case I want to start a new activity from a fragment and send some data (time from a timepicker) back to the fragment that started the activity.

So basically my question is,

How do I start a new Activity from a class that extends fragment?

And then, How do send data back to the fragment.

Comment: startActivityForResult is what you probably need in your fragment imho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to start activity from fragment which deliver you some result back; you can use `startActivityForResult` :

For ex:

```
    public class YourFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final int REQUEST_GET_DATA_FROM_SOME_ACTIVITY = 1;

    //start activity for result
    ....
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),SomeActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_GET_DATA_FROM_SOME_ACTIVITY)

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_GET_DATA_FROM_SOME_ACTIVITY && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
          Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
           //get data from extras
        }
    }

}
```

and inside your activity

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {

      //complete process and deliver result
      ........
      Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
      resultIntent .putExtra("extra","put anything");
      setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
      finish();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a `field` in fragment (you will see usage below)

```
private static int RC_SOME_ACTIVITY = 101;
```

To start activity from fragment

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(getContext(), SomeActivity.class), RC_SOME_ACTIVITY);
```

In the the started activity to send data back

```
Intent data = new Intent();
// add data to intent

setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
finish();
```

In your fragment you will need to override `onActivityResult` to extract data in

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == RC_SOME_ACTIVITY && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // extract data 
    }
}
```